# Finite Arithmetic Progressions - Beginning and End Points

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

First, I want to express the integers 27,29,31,33, and 35 in the form of a finite arithmetic progression. Second, I want to express the integers 37,39,41,43,45, and 47 in the form of a finite arithmetic progression. I know that I can express the first set as 27+2x, but how do I indicate that this sequence ends at 35? Likewise, I know that I can express the second set as 37+2x, but how do I indicate that this sequence ends at 45? How do I express mathematically what the beginning and end points will be? How do I indicate that x can be any whole number from 0 up to a chosen limit?

I need it to be something like this: 27+2x, where x is the set of whole numbers from 0 to 4, expressed in mathematical symbols rather than words.

37+2x, x=0,1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: Let $b$ be the $(n+1)$-th term of a progression with initial term $a$ and common difference $d$. Then $b=a+nd \implies n= \left ( \dfrac{b-a}{d} \right )$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a set, you can use setbuilder notation, $\{27+2x|x \in [0,4]\}$ or $\{27+2x| 0 \le x \le 4\}$and similar.  That does not capture the order, as sets are unordered.  What you want is to write $(27+2i| 0 \le i \le 4)$ with the idea that it is a sequence, not a set, but I am creating it.  If you don't find a standard notation,  define it clearly and use it.